# Python Runtime Profiler?

Tags: python, profiling, benchmarking, profiler

Most python profilers are made for python **programs or scripts**, in my case I'm working with a python plugin for a third-party app (blender 3d), therefore the profiling needs to be sampled in real-time while the user is interacting with the plugin.

I'm currently trying an injection strategy, which consists of **procedurally searching through all plugin modules, & injecting a profiler wrapper to every single function.**

see below, this is what my current profiler looks like

I'm wondering if there are other profilers out there that can be used for run-time scenarios such as plugins

```
class ModuleProfiler: 

    #profiler is running?
    allow = False #must be True in order to start the profiler
    activated = False #read only indication if profiler has been activated

    #please define your plugin main module here
    plugin_main_module = "MyBlenderPlugin"

    #function calls registry 
    registry = {}

    #ignore parameters, typically ui functions/modules
    ignore_fcts = [
        "draw",
        "foo",
        ]
    ignore_module = [
        "interface_drawing",
        ]


    event_prints = True #print all event?

    @classmethod
    def print_registry(cls):
        """print all registered benchmark""" 

        #generate total
        for k,v in cls.registry.copy().items():
            cls.registry[k]["averagetime"] = v["runtime"]/v["calls"]

        print("")
        print("PROFILER: PRINTING OUTCOME")

        sorted_registry = dict(sorted(cls.registry.items(), key=lambda item:item[1]["runtime"], reverse=False))

        for k,v in sorted_registry.items():
            print("\n",k,":")
            for a,val in v.items():
                print(" "*6,a,":",val)

        return None

    @classmethod
    def update_registry(cls, fct, exec_time=0):
        """update internal benchmark with new data"""

        key = f"{fct.__module__}.{fct.__name__}"
        r = cls.registry.get(key)

        if (r is None): 
            cls.registry[key] = {}
            cls.registry[key]["calls"] = 0
            cls.registry[key]["runtime"] = 0
            r = cls.registry[key]

        r["calls"] +=1
        r["runtime"] += exec_time

        return None 

    @classmethod
    def profile_wrap(cls, fct):
        """wrap any functions with our benchmark & call-counter"""

        #ignore some function?
        if (fct.__name__ in cls.ignore_fcts):
            return fct

        import functools
        import time 

        @functools.wraps(fct)
        def inner(*args,**kwargs):
            t = time.time()
            r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
            cls.update_registry(fct, exec_time=time.time()-t)
            if cls.event_prints: 
                print(f"PROFILER : {fct.__module__}.{fct.__name__} : {time.time()-t}")
            return r

        return inner

    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        """inject the wrapper for every functions of every sub-modules of our plugin
        used for benchmark or debugging purpose only"""
            
        if (not cls.allow):
            return None 
        cls.activated = True 
        
        import types
        import sys

        def is_function(obj):
            """check if given object is a function"""
            return isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType)
                
        print("")

        #for all modules in sys.modules
        for mod_k,mod in sys.modules.copy().items():
            
            #separate module componments names
            mod_list = mod_k.split('.')
            
            #fileter what isn't ours
            if (mod_list[0]!=cls.plugin_main_module):
                continue

            #ignore some modules?
            if any([m in cls.ignore_module for m in mod_list]):
                continue
            
            print("PROFILER_SEARCH : ",mod_k)
            
            #for each objects found in module
            for ele_k,ele in mod.__dict__.items():
                
                #if it does not have a name, skip
                if (not hasattr(ele,"__name__")):
                    continue
                
                #we have a global function
                elif is_function(ele):
                    print(f"  INJECT LOCAL_FUNCTION: {mod_k}.{ele_k}")
                    mod.__dict__[ele_k] = cls.profile_wrap(ele)

                #then we have a homebrewed class? search for class.fcts
                #class.fcts implementation is not flawless, need to investigate issue(s)
                elif repr(ele).startswith(f"<class '{cls.plugin_main_module}."):
                    for class_k,class_e in ele.__dict__.items():
                        if is_function(class_e):
                            print(f"  INJECT CLASS_FUNCTION: {mod_k}.{ele_k}.{class_k}")
                            setattr( mod.__dict__[ele_k], class_k, cls.profile_wrap(class_e),) #class.__dict__ are mapping proxies, need to assign this way,
                continue

        print("")

        return None 


ModuleProfiler.allow = True 
ModuleProfiler.plugin_main_module = "MyModule"
ModuleProfiler.start()
```